# Получение доступа к Settings в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

Есть код,в котором есть обращение к Settings:

```
string temp;
Properties.Settings.Defaul.savedString=temp;
```

в Visual Studio 2012 код компилируется нормально.Переустановил винду и поставил VS 13-при компиляции получаю `имя "Properties" не найдено в текущем контексте`.Попробовал проделать то же на компе друга  в VS12-та же ошибка.В статьях  на msdn (  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397759(v=vs.110).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx) 
никакое дополнительное  пространство имен не указано(`using Properties` говорит что такое пространство имен не найдено). Как обратиться к настройкам в VS13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Properties.Settings.Default....();
```

Это файл настроек созданный по умолчанию, вы всегда можете добавить в проект свой файл настроек в любой папке проекта и хранить там что угодно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как обращаться к такому файлу?

Comment: @david_I, Так же как и к стандартному, только вместо "Properties" имя папки(или папок(прописывать через точку)) где лежит файл настроек, а вместо "Settings" имя файла настоек. Естественно файл должен лежать в папке принадлежащей к проекту.